# How to Guarantee Success of HTTP request with Fetch

Tags: http, redux, fetch, redux-thunk

I'm trying to understand what would be the proper way to handle a `fetch` HTTP request and make sure that I receive the data requested.

My point is that something may go wrong with my request, and the required data is critical to my app. In that case, what's the more appropriate way to handle it? Simply create a new request?

And how would I combine the solution with `redux` and `redux-thunk`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**A Guide to Writing Redux Thunk Action Creators that make perform HTTP requests with fetch**

**Preamble**

This example uses isomorphic-fetch which is a promise based library for making HTTP requests. However you can run this example using a different promise based request library such as Axios and it will still work. You can wrap your own HTTP request in a promise if you don't want to use one of these libraries.

**Quick Redux Thunk Example**

Firstly here is a self contained example borrowed from the redux-thunk docs

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

// set up store with redux thunk
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

// thunk action creator
function makeASandwichWithSecretSauce(forPerson) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return fetchSecretSauce().then(
      sauce => dispatch(makeASandwich(forPerson, sauce)),
      error => dispatch(apologize('The Sandwich Shop', forPerson, error))
    );
  };
}

// we can now dispatch the result of our thunk action creator like any other action
store.dispatch(makeASandwichWithSecretSauce('bob))
```

**Representing the statefulness of an HTTP request with Redux actions**

From the Redux docs:

> When you call an asynchronous API, there are two crucial moments in
>   time: the moment you start the call, and the moment when you receive
>   an answer (or a timeout). We first need to define actions and their
>   creators that are associated with making an asynchronous call to an
>   external resource for any given topic id.

There are three possible states of a promise which represents an API request:

- Pending (request made)
- Fulfilled (request successful)
- Rejected (request failed - or timeout)

**Core Action Creators which represent state of request promise**

Okay lets write the core action creators we will need to represent the statefulness of a request for a given topic id.

```
const fetchPending = (topicId) => {
  return { type: 'FETCH_PENDING', topicId }
}

const fetchFulfilled = (topicId, response) => { 
  return { type: 'FETCH_FULFILLED', topicId, response }
}

const fetchRejected = (topicId, err) => {
  return { type: 'FETCH_REJECTED', topicId, err }
}
```

Note that your reducers should handle these actions appropriately.

**Logic for a single fetch action creator**

Fetch is a promise based request library. So the axios.get method makes a request to the given url and returns a promise that will be resolved if successful otherwise this promise will be rejected

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

const makeAPromiseAndHandleResponse = (topicId, url, dispatch) => {
    return fetch(url)
             .then(response => {
               dispatch(fetchFulfilled(topicId, response))
             })
             .catch(err => {
               dispatch(fetchRejected(topicId, err))
             }) 
}
```

If our HTTP request is successful our promise will be resolved and the code in .then will be executed. This will dispatch a FETCH_FULFILLED action for our given topic id with a the response from our request (our topic data)

If the HTTP request is unsuccessful our code in .catch will be executed and dispatch a FETCH_REJECTED action which will contain the topic ID and the error which occurred during the request.

We place our request error handling logic here. This may involve dispatching one or more further actions that could re-attempt the HTTP request or send another one to an alternative URL.

Since this is an asynchronous process we can use a thunk action creator that will use Redux-thunk middleware to allow us to dispatch additional async actions in the future.

**How does a Thunk Action creator work?**

Our thunk action creator has the ability to dispatch multiple actions at a future date.

The set of actions that it will dispatch give information to our reducers about the state of our HTTP request.

The word Thunk is synonymous with delayed evaluation.

This single thunk action creator is an action creator that will be handled by our redux thunk middleware since it fits the signature associated with thunk action creators, that is it returns a function.

**Writing our thunk action creator**

```
export const fetchSomeStuff = (url) => {
    return dispatch => {
        fetchData().then(
            response => dispatch(setOurData(response.data)),
            error => dispatch(apologise(error))
        );
    };
}
```

Our thunk action creator returns a function. This function can return whatever it wants like any normal function so if we want we can set it to return a promise.

```
export const fetchSomeStuff = (url) => {
    return dispatch => {
        return fetchData().then(
            response => dispatch(setOurData(response.data)),
            error => dispatch(apologise(error))
        );
    };
}
```

The fetchSomeStuff  function above is a thunk action creator that calls fetch from the isomorphic-fetch. This action creator therefore returns a promise.

Since we are returning this function inside the function returned by our thunk action creator when we call fetchSomeStuff ( our thunk action creator) we will be returned a promise. This is very useful, especially for tests where we might want to check that certain actions are dispatched at a point in time after we call the thunk action creator.

Our thunk action creator returns the function which we return in our fetchSomeStuff thunk action creator.

Here is the code inside Redux thunk that does this:

```
if (typeof action === 'function') {
  return action(dispatch, getState);
}
```

So if we call

```
fetchSomeStuff('www.example.com')
```

we are returned a function

however if we dispatch fetchSomeStuff

```
store.dispatch(fetchAllItems('www.example.com'))
```

we are returned a promise.

The difference between these two lines of code is that when we dispatch our thunk action creator instead of just calling it naively, it goes through the middleware chain. Redux thunk knows how to deal with functions and will call them.

So essentially this is what happens when redux-thunk middleware is configured and we call store.dispatch

We have our thunk that gets dispatched

```
function thunkActionCreator(){
   return function middlewareInjectsStoreMethods({dispatch, getstate}){  
   }
}
```

When we dispatch this action creator

```
return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
```

This code we have seen before in redux thunk will be executed

```
if (typeof action === 'function') {
  return action(dispatch, getState)
}
```

and we return the result of calling the nested function in our thunk action creator

```
function thunkActionCreator(){
   return function middlewareInjectsStoreMethods({dispatch, getstate}){
   }
}

if (typeof action === 'function') {
    return action(dispatch, getState)
}
```

action represents our thunk action creator whereas calling action inside means we return the nested function called  middlewareInjectsStoreMethods
whereas calling

```
 return action(dispatch, getState)
```

returns  our nested function (middlewareInjectsStoreMethods) and gives  the store's dispatch and getState methods.

Mentally we can think of redux-thunk as doing this

```
if (typeof thunkActionCreator  === 'function') {
     return function middlewareInjectsStoreMethods({dispatch,  getstate}){}
}
```

So now we can see why we have to return a function in our redux thunk action creator.
Our action creator needs access to dispatch further actions in the future. By returning a function we can call it at a later date and STILL have access to dispatch. This elegant way of doing things is part of the reason I am a fan of Redux.